# cannot enable htaccess support on Lion Apache

Tags: macos, .htaccess, apache2, osx-lion

I was running with MAMP for a while but then got to thinking that it wouldn't hurt to get into the bones of Apache itself.

So the default options worked great for me, even enabled a couple of virtual hosts too and they work great. However, I can't get Apache to support my htaccess files.

This is my Apache config https://gist.github.com/1332527 with my virtual host config as well https://gist.github.com/1332542

My sites work at min.local/index.php/some-url for example but fail at min.local/some-url where I get a 404. I've read a number of blog posts about setting AllowOverride to All in httpd.conf but it hasn't made a difference.

My .htaccess file is fine, it works in production.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the `AllowOverride None` in the virtual host file is overriding the `AllowOverride All` in the main config file.  Try changing it to `All` and see what happens.

Comment: yeah I did try that before but that gives: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /some-url on this server.

Comment: In that case, I'm pretty sure there's something in the .htaccess that's causing trouble.  Since it works in production, there's probably something different between the two environments that it's tripping over.

Answer (score 4):

Also, make sure to look at your user-specific conf file, located at /etc/apache2/users/username.conf and set your AllowOverride there.

The settings there will override the defaults in httpd.conf

just set it to All or whatever you have in httpd

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. In my vhost block I had to add

```
<Directory "{webroot path}">
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

On restarting apache (sudo apachectl restart) all was good.